# Android and getting a view with id cast as a string

Tags: java, android, layout

In the Java code of an Android project if you want the reference for a view resource you can do something like:

```
View addButton = findViewById(R.id.button_0);
```

In the above R.id.button_0 is not a String. Is it possible to dynamically refer to a resource by a string, such as "`R.id.button_0`"?

I'd like to refer to a button by "`R.id.button_%i`" where `%i` is replaced by some valid index.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("button_%i",
    "id", getPackageName());
View addButton = findViewById(resID);
```

where `%i` is replaced by some valid index.

The `getResources()` method belongs to the `Context` class, so you can use that directly from an `Activity`. If you are not inside an activity, then use a context to access: (`myCtxt.getResources()`).

Comment: Note this is going to be significantly slower than using the ID directly.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. Btw, I fixed a compile error in this code sample.

Comment: @hackbod why will it be slower? if you, or someone else, could point to a doc reference for your assertion, it would be great.

Comment: It is slower because instead of accessing the ID (which is just a plain Java constant), it will call a bunch of methods that will likely use reflection in order to obtain the constant value. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502674/why-reflection-is-slow

Comment: @VinayWadhwa In my experience, using this in a loop caused such poor performance it is not acceptable.

Comment: using of getIdentifier is not recommended anymore

Answer (score 4):

You could try putting all the ids you want in an array and then using that array to dynamically refer to your resources instead.

Comment: This could be a good approach for some special occasions (when the name of the resources changes or the order is complex); otherwise I think it's not the better way to do it. Some times you will end up with a huge array which makes your code look smelly.

Comment: @cristian it does indeed make horrible nasty code. Where i've done this in the past i've shoved it in its own static class. But your approach seems somewhat nicer ;)