# can BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context,int) take context string

Tags: android, image, resources, bitmapfactory

I have a method that returns a String(let's say the var sprite) and this string is the name of my bitmap img,and i want to use it with BitmapFactory.decodeResource() but i don't know how to combine this since it must be int R.drawable.sprite

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Take a look at this question:

[Android and getting a view with id cast as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730100/android-and-getting-a-view-with-id-cast-as-a-string)