# Reference drawable by name

Tags: android, drawable

I have a database holding a lot of static data for my current application.  One of the tables in the database gives various information about a list of items.  It would make sense for it to hold a reference to the graphic for each item, too.  The graphics are stored in a drawable folder and referenced by R.drawable in the application.  Am I able to reference them by their name so that I can store the names as strings in the database?  If not, is there an obvious method for doing this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Am I able to reference them by their name so that I can store the names as strings in the database?

Yes. Take a look at this answer:

[Android and getting a view with id cast as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730100/android-and-getting-a-view-with-id-cast-as-a-string)