# How to convert a string into a path

Tags: android

How to convert a string like "R.drawable.online" into a path, which can represent an image?
What should I do for this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer:

[Android and getting a view with id cast as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730100/android-and-getting-a-view-with-id-cast-as-a-string)

By the way... that kind of resources cannot be access using a *path*... you must use the integer representation of it.

Answer (score 0):

if you have an image inside your folder /drawable/online.png
you will load your image for example into a ImageView...

> ImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.online));