# Can I store the int IDs of drawable in an XML?

Tags: java, android

So I'm trying to organize my data into an XML as such:

```
<hands>
    <punch>
        <id>1</id>
        <move>Reverse Punch</move>
        <jap>Gyaku Zuki</jap>
        <thumb>2130837505</thumb>
    </punch>
</hands>
```

The data from the XML gets parsed and ends up in a hashmap. I'd like to draw them like so:

```
thumb.setImageURI(Uri.parse(Main.ROOT + Integer.parseInt(moveList.get(MoveView.KEY_THUMB))));
```

Is using the ID instead of referencing them via R.drawable.img alright?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not store the constants from `R` class and you should always refer to them by `R.drawable.img`. The reason for it is that the integer values may change at any time and are not guaranteed to be the same every time you build your app.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Is there any way to draw them from a string?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730100/android-and-getting-a-view-with-id-cast-as-a-string

Comment: another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427608/android-getting-resource-id-from-string

Answer (score 1):

You should store the name of image in drawable. In your case you should store "img" and use this code to get android Id in your app:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(elementName,"drawable", getPackageName());
```